# page not found 404 - Index Action

Tags: asp.net-core

My solution was working very well, suddenly I got (page not found 404 error) for two controllers only for Index Actions !!
and the other Index actions in other controllers are working fine.

**UsersController**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.Users.ToListAsync());
}
[HttpPost]

public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromForm] string search)
{
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
    {

        search = search.Trim().ToLower();
        ViewBag.Search = search;
        return View(_context.Users.Where(x => x.NormalizedUsername.Contains(search)).ToList());
    }
    else
        return View(await _context.Users.ToListAsync());
}
```

any help/clue where I should check?
thanks

Comment: I think the problem is routing. You could place a route on the controller or action.

Comment: Hi @MomenAlnaser, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 1):

> I got (page not found 404 error) for two controllers only for Index Actions

Please check the conventional routing you configured in `StartUp.Configure` method, then compare it with your actual request URL and check if some required segment or data is missing in request URL.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#conventional-routing

And please check if you are using any attribute route or URL rewriting rule, which might cause similar issue.

Besides, you can try to modify log level to get detailed routing diagnostic logs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#debug-diagnostics